# Using regular expressions to parse occurrences of %SOMETEXT% out of a string

Tags: c#

I never use Regular expressions because they seem so complicated though I know that they are dense and powerful.  I thought I would give them a shot with your help

How do I use regular expressions to extract all occurences of %sometext% in a string variable and return a string array of matching items?

For example, if the input string is:

```
set NewVariable=%Variable1%%Variable2%%Variable3%SomeText%Variable4%
```

The output array would be:

```
Array[0]=Variable1
Array[1]=Variable2
Array[2]=Variable3
Array[3]=Variable4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should look like this:

```
%([^%]*)%
```

The delimiters are on both sides, the capturing group is i between them.

Here is how:

```
var mc = Regex.Matches(
    "quick%brown%%fox%jumps%over%the%lazy%%dog%"
,   "%([^%]*)%"
);
foreach (Match m in mc) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

The output of the above looks like this:

```
brown
fox
over
lazy
dog
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/deEJhJ).

Answer (score 1):

```
var NewVariable = "%Variable1%%Variable2%%Variable3%SomeText%Variable4%";
var Array = Regex.Matches(NewVariable, @"%(.+?)%")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is `%[^%]+%` . Look at the [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) method.